# Multiple box shadows on a single element using Bourbon

Tags: css

I want to put two box shadows on a single element. The following doesn't work:

```
@include box-shadow(1px 1px 488px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) inset);
@include box-shadow(4px 4px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28));
```

Not does providing a comma-separated list of box shadows into the `box-shadow` mixin (it only takes one argument). How can I accomplish this? I'm using the Boubon gem, but a straight CSS solution is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the link for how to do this

[Is there a way to use two CSS3 box shadows on one element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556604/is-there-a-way-to-use-two-css3-box-shadows-on-one-element)

The gist of it is to try using comma separated ones, I know you said you tried this already but maybe double check with the syntax they suggest in the answer to the link?

Answer (score 0):

[Bourbon's `box-shadow` mixin has been deprecated](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/1913) as the usage for prefixing browsers has dropped below the threshold. Just use regular ol' CSS:

```
box-shadow: 
    1px 1px 488px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) inset,
    4px 4px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
```

Side-note: I'd watch out for using such a massive blur-radius; that might get pretty bad performance on slower machines. If you're using it as a huge background gradient, it might be better to add that gradient as another background `linear-gradient` layer.