# Multiple box shadows on one element, with different settings

Tags: html, css

After reading [Is there a way to use two CSS3 box shadows on one element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556604/is-there-a-way-to-use-two-css3-box-shadows-on-one-element) , I figured out how to apply two box shadows to one class. However, I want to manipulate these two box shadows separately but apply them to the same element. I tried using a divider and two separate classes, but that didn't yield the right results.

**Specifically what I'm trying to do is this:**
On hover, scale the icon up, and fade in a border. After a short delay, start a pulsating effect, with the border still on. When the cursor is moved away, have all effects fade out and icon scale to normal size.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3o0ttrrs/)

```
.nav img {
transition: 0.3s ease;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: 30px; }

.nav img:hover {
transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
-webkit-animation: pulsate 2.0s ease-out 0.3s infinite;
border-radius: 50%;
transition: 0.3s ease; }

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate { 
0% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);}
50% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0), 0 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);}
100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0), 0 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);}}
```

**So I'm having two problems.** 
The first is that the entire effect eases in at the same time, but I want the inner border to fade in first. I feel like adding more keyframes and adjusting the timing of the pulsating effect might work but could make the animation appear choppy.
The second is that when you stop hovering, the box shadows immediately disappear without fading or easing out.

I was wondering if it could be done by just layering the icon, border, and pulsating effect, then using javascript to activate all of them on mouseover.
If anyone could provide some input it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved my issue with a different approach.** I layered a second circle behind it and kept the blinking effect on the actual object. From there, using the CSS `+` operator, I could manipulate both circles, having the outer circle fade in when hovering over the inner circle. [Working version](https://jsfiddle.net/khtw6qnr/)