# How can I add a border to the right side of this object?

Tags: css

How can I add a border to the right side of this object to complete the square with the same properties as the border of the left. Adding box-shadow: 20px 0 0 0 red; does not work but overrides the left border.

https://jsfiddle.net/kheuz1z4/

HTML

CSS

```
#borders {
  border-top: 20px solid black;
  box-shadow: -20px 0 0 0 red;
  border-bottom: 20px solid green;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can comma seperate box-shadow:

```
  #borders {
  border-top: 20px solid black;
  box-shadow: -20px 0 0 0 red, 20px 0 0 0 red;
  border-bottom: 20px solid green;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}
```

Source: [Is there a way to use two CSS3 box shadows on one element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556604/is-there-a-way-to-use-two-css3-box-shadows-on-one-element)

Answer (score 0):

```
border-top-right-radius:  //Value
```

I think you can find a solution by adding the top css file

Answer (score 0):

```
#borders {
  border-top: 20px solid black;
  border-right: 20px solid black, , 20px 0 0 0 red;
  box-shadow: -20px 0px 0 0 red;
  border-bottom: 20px solid green;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}
```

Please check if you want like this https://jsfiddle.net/kheuz1z4/2/

[image]

Comment: you can change the color as u wish, Please mark it answered if it works..