# How to create specific css scroll shadow?

Tags: css

Actually, I'm working on some CSS improvements and I need some help with a specific action.

I have this CSS code that renders a shadow on scroll :

```
.scrollGradient {
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff 33%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
    linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #ffffff 66%) 0 100%,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 0, rgba(186, 186, 186, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(186, 186, 186, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 20px, 100% 20px, 100% 10px, 100% 10px;
    background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
}
```

Result:

[image]

And actually, I want the top shadow to be like this :
[image]

Could you give me some help please?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a shadow with the [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) CSS property:

```css
.scrollGradientTop {
    /* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | color */
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px -15px #000000;
}
```

If you want to only show the shadow when scrolling you need to use to use some JavaScript:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.scrollGradient');
el.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (el.scrollTop === 0) {
    el.classList.remove('scrollGradientTop');
  } else {
    el.classList.add('scrollGradientTop');
  }
});
```

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.scrollGradient');
el.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (el.scrollTop === 0) {
    el.classList.remove('scrollGradientTop');
  } else {
    el.classList.add('scrollGradientTop');
  }
});
```

```css
.scrollGradient {
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff 33%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #ffffff 66%) 0 100%, radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 0, rgba(186, 186, 186, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(186, 186, 186, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 20px, 100% 20px, 100% 10px, 100% 10px;
  background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
}

.scrollGradientTop {
  box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px -15px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollGradient" style="width: 500px; max-height: 200px; overflow: scroll; margin: 50px;">
  <div style="min-height: 10000px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @David :) ! One more question, how can I do to make it appear only when scrolling down ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think that it is possible to do that only with CSS. I have added in my answer how to do it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

In your existing code you are setting the background of your element.

What you need is [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).

There are plenty of online tools like [this one](https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/) to generate `box-shadow` if you dont want to do it manually.

If you need more than one shadows for the same element, you can separate them with a comma, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8556627/5827913).

Comment: How can I add box-shadow for top and bottom ?

Comment: @ims16 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556604/is-there-a-way-to-use-two-css3-box-shadows-on-one-element

Comment: @anpel can i do it for top and bottom at the same time ?

Comment: @ims16 Yes, you can use multiple box shadows as mentioned in the question linked in my earlier comment. This stuff is well-documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow. I suggest reading that first.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys :) One last question, can I apply the scroll mechanism with this value ?     background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;

Comment: @ims16 what are you trying to achieve with that? Maybe this could be helpful? https://lea.verou.me/2012/04/background-attachment-local/

Comment: I want the same scroll shadow, but more like :

- Top shadow on scroll should be out of the div

Comment: @ims16 in that case I believe the link above should help.